# how to submit a hidden form HTML JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I want to update a field in my html form separately from the rest. I know we can't have embedded forms in html so how can I make this work?

```
<form name="LabelForm" method='POST' action="lab/CA/ALL/createLabel.do">
                <input type="hidden" name="lab_no" value="<%=lab_no%>">
                <input type="hidden" name="aNum" value="<%=aNum%>">
                <input type="hidden" name="label" value="<%=label%>">
                <td><input type="submit" value="Create" /></td>
</form>
```

In the above code, the submit button is outside the main table which is part of another form called ackform. I want to put the submit button in the main table(so everything's neat and orderly)  but make it part of LabelForm. The value that is entered by the user is "label" which I want to submit with the LabelForm.

Comment: I think you need to re-word this a little. It's hard to figure out exactly what you want. You can't submit "part of a form", but you can have a hidden form that submits to a hidden iframe. You can use JavaScript to copy data from your main form, put in in the hidden form and submit from there.

Comment: label is a user input value in another <textarea> field. So I want to assign whatever the user writes in the <textarea> to the jsp var <%label%> and submit the form

Comment: @Sapphire yup! JavaScript would do the trick for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my guess:

```
<form name="TDISLabelForm" method='POST' action="lab/CA/ALL/createLabelTDIS.do">
   <input type="hidden" name="lab_no" value="<%=lab_no%>">
   <input type="hidden" name="accessionNum" value="<%=accessionNum%>">
   <input type="hidden" id="label" name="label" value="<%=label%>">
   <td><input type="submit" value="Create" /> <input type="button" onclick="form2.submit()" value="save in the hidden form">
</td>
</form>

<form name="form2" target="fr1" action="....your post code..." method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="label" name="label" value="<%=label%>">
</form>
<iframe style="height:1px;width:1px;border:none:" id="fr1"></iframe>
```

Comment: I tried this but the value of "label" is not being handed over to the action class...When a user clicks the create button, it has to submit the value entered in the "label" field.